# APA citation of a published interview

Tags: citations, citation-style

I am strugging to find a consistent answer on how to correctly reference a chapter in a book, that is an interview. (The book in question is avaliable as PDF [here](http://quod.lib.umich.edu/cgi/p/pod/dod-idx/new-materialism-interviews-cartographies.pdf?c=ohp;idno=11515701.0001.001))

The book is edited by two authors who interviewing one person per chapter. I sometimes quote the interviewers (the book editors), sometimes the interviewee.

I have seen various ways of referencing in this situation.

**A)** Interviewee as author - which feels right when the interviewee is quoted, but wrong when the quote refers to the question.

> Barad, K. (2012). Interview with Karen Barad. In R. Dolphijn and I.
>   van der Tuin (Eds.), New materialism: Interviews & cartographies (1.
>   ed, pp. 48–70). Ann Arbor, MI: Open Humanities Press.

**B)** Interviewers as authors - which feels right, but when using more than 1 interview adds up as multiple citations plus disguises the interviewee in in-text citation.

(Dolphijn & Tuin, 2012a)
(Dolphijn & Tuin, 2012b)

> Dolphijn, R. & Tuin, I. van der. (2012a). Interview with Rosi
>   Braidotti. In R. Dolphijn and I. van der Tuin (Eds.), New materialism:
>   Interviews & cartographies (1. ed, pp. 19–37). Ann Arbor, MI: Open
>   Humanities Press.
>
> Dolphijn, R. & Tuin, I. van der. (2012b). Interview with Karen Barad.
>   In R. Dolphijn and I. van der Tuin (Eds.), New materialism: Interviews
>   & cartographies (1. ed, pp. 48–70). Ann Arbor, MI: Open Humanities
>   Press.

**C)** Using all authors involved. I have seen this in other author's references but I have not found any guideline that suggests doing this.

(Barad et al., 2012)

> Barad, K., Dolphijn, R. & Tuin, I. van der. (2012). Interview with
>   Rosi Braidotti. In R. Dolphijn and I. van der Tuin (Eds.), New
>   materialism: Interviews & cartographies (1. ed, pp. 19–37). Ann Arbor,
>   MI: Open Humanities Press.

The voice of the author probably needs to be identified in-text, but which of these 3 bibliography versions is correct APA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [APA guidance on handling interviews](http://www.apastyle.org/learn/quick-guide-on-references.aspx#Interviews), if it is an interview not done by you found in a standard source (book chapter, in your case) then you follow the normal formatting for that source (book chapter if you are summarizing the whole interview; book as a whole if you are taking quotes from the interview with matching citation in-text that denotes speaker of quote).

With regards to the book chapter formatting in this case involving multiple people (interviewer, interviewee, etc.), the [APA style blog](http://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/book/) has all the details on how to capture all of the different authors in the case of a book chapter.  Most of these details apply to the idea of multiple "authors" in the book.  Interviewees wouldn't be classified as authors (i.e., they aren't listed in the front matter of the book as authors), so you don't need to worry about that in this case.

For your specific case, I would do the reference as the whole book, not individual chapters, and not listing the authors as editors as they are credited as writing the whole book in its front matter, and not listing the names of the interviewees in the reference itself (as explained in the APA guidance links):

> Dolphijn, R., & Tuin, I. van der. (2012). *New materialism: Interviews & cartographies* (1st ed.). Ann Arbor, MI: Open Humanities Press.

Then, I would do the in-text citations in a manner that highlights the speaker of the quotes and the location in the book:

> As stated by Rosi Braidotti, "[insert quote from interview here]" (Dolphijn & Tuin, 2012, Chapter 1, p. [insert single page number of quote]).

When you are quoting the authors of the book, not the interviewee, the in-text citation should just be:

> "[insert quote from authors here]" (Dolphijn & Tuin, 2012, p. [insert single page number of quote]).

In this manner, you keep your reference style consistent with the standard APA book reference style and you clarify the speaker of each quote using the in-text citation, which is the recommended APA method.  You don't want to cite the whole chapter in either case because the result would not specify the specific page where the quote was found.  You would only cite the whole chapter if you were summarizing the chapter's insights as a whole.

Comment: Thanks! So in this case I should go with option B then?!

Comment: Sorta.  See update to answer.